# Is there a simple upgrade process for existing MVC projects to MVC6 RC1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am planning to migrate my existing ASP.NET MVC 4 project to ASP.NET MVC 6, Can someone please guide me or give step by step solution to achieve.

I have tried to find out solution online but most of articles and solutions are available for migration of MVC 4 to MVC 5 not for MVC4 to  MVC6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a guide to updating from MVC5 to MVC6 [here](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfrommvc5.html).  However, this is really only helpful for trivial projects.

Updating from Identity 2 and EntityFramework 6 to Identity 3 and EntityFramework 7 is not trivial.  The identity upgrade pretty much means throwing out your old Account Controller/Views and replacing with new ones.

MVC 6 / ASP.NET 5 are quite different to their predecessors.  If you are set on upgrading, I would recommend creating a new ASP.NET 5 Web Application and piece by piece moving your MVC 4 components over to it so you can get an understanding of what is/is not supported, and how the two technologies differ.  This will also slowly introduce you to the errors you're going to find, rather than just trying to immediately convert an MVC 4 project to ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 (even if that were possible).

Comment: Thank you Stafford Williams for your comment, I agree with your answer that we should to create new ASP.NET 5 web application and start doing one by one module coding, but my client wants to directly migrate entire application from MVC 4 to MVC 6.

Comment: @ManojSitapara Then your best bet is to create a new, empty MVC 6 project, and move the pieces from your MVC 4 project into it one by one.

Comment: Okay I will do that, so there is not any chance that we can immediately migrate from MVC4 to MVC6, right?

Comment: Not like the previous versions no.  MVC6/ASP.NET 5 is a paradigm change.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and your answer really helps me a lot.